# How can I do lines of a single string sleep before being printed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I'm developing a interactive fiction game and up to now I do lines sleep just like this:

```
def pn(n): print(n); time.sleep(2)  #print narrative


n1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer"
n2 = "quis purus eu lorem lobortis aliquam. Nunc imperdiet orci ac"
n3 = "justo lacinia fringilla."


pn(n1); pn(n2); pn(n3)
```

I would like to make a single string like:

```
nX = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
quis purus eu lorem lobortis aliquam. Nunc imperdiet orci ac
justo lacinia fringilla."""
```

And sleep two seconds each line, is there a way to do that? I've searched over Python 3.3 documentation and couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by lines in your last example? Split it into sentences you mean? Or do you have embedded newlines in the string (after `Integer` and `ac`)?

Comment: Personally, I'd find it really frustrating to play an IF game which sleeps for two seconds between printing each line. If you're looking to do an Infocom-esque game, take a look at [Inform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inform) - it's much simpler than writing all this from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to split the text into lines to print. If you already have newlines in the text, split with [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
for line in nX.splitlines():
    pn(line)
```

`.splitlines()` splits text on line separators, which can vary depending on platform.

Otherwise you'll need to find the points where to split the text into sentences. Using a regular expression would give you the most bang for the buck:

```
import re

sentence_end = re.compile(r'(?<=[.?!])\s+')

for sentence in sentence_end.split(nX):
   pn(sentence)
```

This uses a look-behind assertion to make sure that the text is split on whitespace that is preceded by end-of-sentence punctuation (`.`, `?` or `!`).

Splitting on sentences otherwise ignores newlines:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence_end = re.compile(r'(?<=[.?!])\s+')
>>> sentence_end.split(nX)
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'Integer\nquis purus eu lorem lobortis aliquam.', 'Nunc imperdiet orci ac\njusto lacinia fringilla.']
```

Comment: Perfect answer using my own defined function, it will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Just turn your string into many strings, iterate over them and add some delay in each iteration.

```
>>> nX = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
... quis purus eu lorem lobortis aliquam. Nunc imperdiet orci ac
... justo lacinia fringilla."""
```

```
>>> nX.splitlines()
```

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer', 'quis purus eu lorem lobortis aliquam. Nunc imperdiet orci ac', 'justo lacinia fringilla.']
```

```
>>> for line in nX.splitlines():
...     print(line)
...     time.sleep(2)
...
```

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
pause
quis purus eu lorem lobortis aliquam. Nunc imperdiet orci ac
pause
justo lacinia fringilla.
pause
```